# Keep Python Script Running on Server

Tags: python, server, cgi-bin

I am using HelioHost server, and I have a Python script which weekly generates a graph which I would like to show on a webpage. I would like to know how to keep this Python script running constantly on the server for it to perform this task. I have uploaded it to the public_html/CGI-BIN, however this is only executed when I access the address (if my understanding is correct).

Therefore, how can I execute it and keep it running on the server?

Comment: Dont know much more about HelioHost server but I think you can use cron job for the same. IT will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it has to generate a graph, I suspect that it should do so periodically, not constantly. For that kind of scenario, cron is your friend. Set up a cron job to run the script periodically. A crontab entry to execute your script every minute could look like this:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script
```